# Battery size for street musician gear

Tags: batteries, amplifier, automotive, music

I am a musician and we are taking our show to the streets, away from wall sockets.  For this, we will be using a 300W inverter that I have lying around,  with a car battery of some size {?}

We have:

- two AER C60 amps  60 W at 230V
- a mixer that says it takes 23W at 230V, and
- two 12V 300mA  (3,6 W each) wireless receivers that we use to run 2 voices, guitar and fiddle.

at 230 V  we have 2x 60 W=120  23W + 7,2 W = 150, 2W Maximum power. I am a layman, but surely the amps would not be taking 60W all the time?

My question is: What size of battery do I need to run this at half volume for 5 hours?

Thanks very much for your thoughts

Comment: 300mAh wireless receivers? Say what now? mA maybe..

Comment: you are right...my bad...  12V300mA

Comment: Just a thought: you are aware many cities do allow street music but disallow the use of amplifiers?

Comment: Yes... this is why it is such a great thing that we are booked to play at fairs and venues, that will pay us to be the day's mobile, amped entertainment..:)

Answer (score 3):

Let me suggest a process, connect it all up play it at the volume you want and measure the current that is being taken from a 12V battery. Call this x amps.

To get reasonable longevity out of a lead acid battery you need to aim at a discharge of 50% of the capacity.

The capacity you want is x * 5 * 2 Ah.

Comment: Thank you so much...! (As a teacher, I know the best answers are the ones that are easiest to follow..) I wil get an amp meter and find out...

Answer (score 1):

Get a leisure battery (like 90Ah) and one of those cheap Chinese digital ammeters available from the usual sources - I'd suggest a 50A one, which is comfortably above what your 300W inverter will use.

(Run the ammeter off a disposable 9V battery, you can't run it from the battery you're measuring. I do this on my boat).

Now set this up and see what it does during a jam session, and design the system based on what you learn.

Flat out, it would take 25-30A, which would consume 50-60Ah from your battery in 2 hours. (You didn't tell us anything about the amplifiers If they take too much power, the inverter will limit power, and maybe complain and shut down). You don't want to drain the battery any deeper than this.

So you probably need at least 2 of these batteries. You can connect two via a 2-way battery isolator switch - again, cheaply available from the usual sources or a caravan/RV store or marine chandlers, and can disconnect about a thousand amps.

If you need a third battery, disconnect the one you're not using and connect a spare, during a short break between songs.

Rig the isolator switch and ammeter in a suitable box. You can get separate carrying boxes for the leisure batteries, providing some weather protection.

Comment: Thanks so much! The amps are 60W by 230V, but they would never take so much all the time, i don't think..

Answer (score -2):

You need to figure out how much power your equipment takes.  Your information is garbled due to be sloppy with the physics.  We can understand you may not know much about electronics, but we expect people coming here to at least understand basic units.  Otherwise, we have nothing to talk about.

Trying to dissect your question:

> 300W inverter

That tells you the maximum power the inverter can put out.  This number either tells you whether the inverter can do the job or not.  It doesn't tell you battery drain, other than to set a vague upper limit.  Hopefully your equipment takes substantially less than 300 W.

> two AER C60 amps at 230v

This is completely useless.  Volts aren't Watts, assuming the lower case "v" is meant to indicate volts.  See high school physics.  A small night light and a toaster can both run from 230 V, but the second draws vastly more power, and would drain a battery much faster, then the second.

> mixer ... 23W at 230V

This is the spec you need for all your equipment.  Add up the power for everything.  OK, we're up to 23 W now.

> two 12V 300mAh wireless receivers

More nonsense physics.  "mAh" is a unit of charge.  That's as useless as volts for figuring the power requirements.

In short, there is nothing we can do here.  Repeating basic high school physics would be too much for a post here, but without it you aren't giving us sensible specs.

You could try to meaure the battery current with everything connected.  That would require putting a ammeter in series with the battery.  If that makes any sense, report back what the current is.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time for your reply. I have upped the data, the total power consumption would be 150 W, if the amps were to take 60W each all the time.

Comment: Unfortunately 60W is the audio output rating of the amps. The power consumption will be higher depending on the amp and the volume . Measure it!